# MongoDB Liveness Probe

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, livenessprobe

Why do we need liveness probe for MongoDB with command `db.adminCommand('ping')` ?
I mean, is there any scenario the main process of Mongo doesn't exit but still mongo doesn't function? Because kubelet automatically restarts container if the main process exits.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70075319/2777988